# Android Scroll ListViewfrom code

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to have a piece of code cause a ListViewto scroll. This is happening as another view is being scrolled. Currently I'm calling scrollBy(x,y) on this ListView to cause it to scroll. This causes the items in the list to scroll but does not cause new items to be loaded. I've tried calling invalidate on the list but this does not seem to work. The problem appears to be that what the list understands as visible items are only updated by touch events.

Does anyone know a way to get around this?

Comment: Try calling notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter of the list not updating when you call the scrollBy method.

Comment: No dice. The data doesn't need to be refreshed. It's all there.

Comment: right, it forces the listview to redraw as well, but seems like that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that ScrollBy and ScrollTo are methods of the base View, and thus seems to be scrolling the whole 'viewport' of the list.
If you want to scroll the items use smoothScrollBy or smoothScrollToPosition.
That should work